# Cannot "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit"

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

When reviewing [this Suggested Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15287742), I could not found the <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> and <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd> buttons.

[image]

Also, it (i.e. the top one named *VSFTPD and Symfony*) seems quite different from others in the review history: it's a line of text rather than a hyper link.

[image]

I want to know what makes this edit so special?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The post was deleted.  Since it was deleted you can't actually access it to edit it.  That is why you can only accept or reject it.

Edit suggestions to a deleted question should be removed from the review queue after a slight delay.  I think it is like 15 minutes.

Comment: No, it seems to be at least 4 hours from my experience.